# Get the data from the JsonArray

Tags: android

this is my JSON result when I print the log.I am not able to get the data from this result.Please suggest how to get the data from this result. The error shows the of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject.I know there are already many posts related to this but I can't understand how to get the data.

```
09-12 05:12:57.606: W/System.err(3385): org.json.JSONException: Value 
[
  {
    "client": [
      {
        "office_name": "",
        "is_verified": "1",
        "forum_email_notification": "1",
        "city": "",
        "first_name": "Pratik",
        "balance": "0",
        "option_domain_name": "Vision",
        "initials": "Mr",
        "client_type": "0",
        "group_credit": "0.00",
        "gender": "0",
        "is_approved": "1",
        "domain_name": "Vision",
        "client_id": "2",
        "otherim": "",
        "credit": "0.00",
        "is_spam": "0",
        "office_phone": "",
        "parent_id": "0",
        "domain_url": "http://example.com/vision4/sandip/v5/",
        "fax": "",
        "forum_signature_content": "",
        "group_id": "1",
        "optionB_domain_id": "1",
        "country": "",
        "contact_number": "",
        "user_name": "test",
        "email": "pratik@test.com",
        "job_title": "",
        "last_name": "T",
        "parent_name": "",
        "temporary_address": "",
        "facebook_id": "",
        "language": "1",
        "office_contact_num": "",
        "salt": "e2e838b89b16f488a901b3b364ad839e",
        "zip_code": "",
        "office_website": "",
        "department": "",
        "state": "",
        "office_fax": "",
        "login_as": "0",
        "currency": "USD",
        "permanent_address": "",
        "department_access": "0",
        "is_manager": "0",
        "birthdate": "",
        "registration_date": "1504254310",
        "parent_email": "",
        "password_auth": "0",
        "group_name": "Default",
        "netmeetingid": "",
        "website": "",
        "domain_id": "1",
        "is_banned": "0",
        "twitter_id": "",
        "mobile_number": "",
        "office_address": "",
        "authentication": "383Y4A==",
        "harvest_id": "0",
        "image_path": "",
        "office_email": ""
      }
    ],
    "unsolve": 3,
    "solve": 0
  }
]
of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Comment: How are you trying to get the data fro your json string? (please add the code here)

Comment: What you had done so far ?

Answer (score 0):

It's because your result is an array of JSONObject and not a JSONObject itself

Comment: Yes benjamin but I am new to android.

Comment: Problem get solved by following solution.

String result =client_array.toString();
          try 
{

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
JSONObject actualData = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
JSONObject response = actualData.getJSONObject("client");
String fname=response.getString(FIRST_NAME);